# url is not being inserted in database correctly

Tags: mysql, url

I am trying to insert 
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=plagerism 
in mysql database. The data type is varchar(500).

But what i get in the field is

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm%3Dplagerism

Can anyone help me explain how i can fix this.

Thanks

Comment: how get the value for insert i mean from witch variable or function befor insert to database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at PHP's URLencode() and URLdecode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

what is the code you use for inserting into database?

I would guess there is a part that reqrites part of the data to prevent SQL Injection...